# onclick event not firing in a for loop

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I'm binding (or at least trying to) a function for each li element under a ul.

But the event never fires. Take a look at the code below, the alert saying "foo"
is showing, but the next one saying "bar" is supposed to show once a click 
on the li tag is invoked.

```
function set_search_value() 
{
    var e = document.getElementById("res_ls");

    alert("foo");
    for (var i = 0; i < e.children.length; i++) 
    {
        e.children[i].onclick = function() {
            alert("bar");
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="res_ls" class="visible">
 <li><span><span class="highlighted">test</span>ing.com</span> <span>(181)</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your `<script>` is maybe positioned somewhere above the elements, maybe in the `<head>`, and is running before the elements have loaded. If so, put your `<script>` just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: All of that is happening a lot after the dom has loaded.

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same ID? What does it show if you do `alert(e)` before the loop?

Comment: Nope. That id is unique

Comment: Have you tried doing an alert or a log (or a breakpoint) inside the loop to check if it accesses the right elements?

Comment: Well, it works fine here. http://jsfiddle.net/MyNeT/ Whatever the issue is, you haven't represented it in the question. Open your browser's developer console to look for errors.

Comment: @pixelcdv There is an alert right there in my code -.-

Comment: @elad.chen not **in** the loop, only outside. With this you cannot know if e isn't null or if it indeed have children

Comment: Issue solved. I was adding an EventListener instead of just invoking the function (which I shouldn't have). No reason to down vote -.-

Comment: No reason to down vote? Of course there is. You posted working code, and claimed that it didn't work. Now we find that you didn't bother to post the actual problematic code for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped your exact code into a jsFiddle and it appears to function as desired: http://jsfiddle.net/qVQU4/

I have one piece of advice to offer, though: Attaching individual click handlers to each `<li>` element can be problematic for performance reasons in long lists, and also requires extra coding gymnastics if items in the list are being manipulated via javascript on the client side. A better technique would be to attach a single event handler to the parent container, and let the click bubble up to that level.

Here's an example using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/qVQU4/1/

```
$("#res_ls").on("click", "li", function(e) { 
    // e.target will be set to the <li> element that was clicked
    alert("bar");
});
```

Using the latter technique, any new items added to the list will have their clicks handled automatically, without having to wire any additional event handlers.

Comment: Yeah I though about it too, but I couldn't get to that solution using just javascript. (I do not use jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example on the jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/drfisher/Ts7wZ/

```
var children = document.getElementById("res_ls").children;
var child;

for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
    child = children[i];
    if (child.nodeType == 1) {
        child.onclick = function() {
           alert(this.textContent);
        }
    }
}
```